# How can I pass headers in grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, http-headers, ruby-grape, grape-api

How can I pass headers in grape with post method?

I am passing the header as follows. This method is not working.

```
resource :pay do
  post :new_order do
    key = header("#{params[:key]}")
    sign = header("#{params[:sign]}") 
    method = params[:method]
    nonce = DateTime.now.to_i
    order_type = params[:type]
    rate = params[:price]
    quantity = params[:amount]

    HTTParty.post("https://www.coins-e.com/api/v2/market/WDC_BTC/")
  end
end
```

The above API call is for [image: click here]

I passed the post request dynamically in chrome rest client. It gives the correct response. 
Check with

**Method**: post

**Url**: https://www.coins-e.com/api/v2/market/LTC_BTC/

**Headers**:

key :ba57bca64f2adf4721dfd972392321608c38a955370f8349e11f679d

sign:551a7b9a02a4e3ad811cb9f40546135879978e18f1e35f3414410d77a2fdff183941f0593b913695eae18d9236eb3466e01e01026ffb95411e66042078d918a1

**Body**:

method=neworder&nonce=1403675015&order_type=buy&rate=0.002312&quantity=0.002312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the HTTParty gem for that.

For this example you don't need to use headers, you can use query param:

```
HTTParty.post("https://www.coins-e.com/api/v2/market/WDC_BTC/",
    :query => { :key => "ba57bca64f2adf4721dfd972392321608c38a955370f8349e11f679d", :sign => "551a7b9a02a4e3ad811cb9f40546135879978e18f1e35f3414410d77a2fdff183941f0593b913695eae18d9236eb3466e01e01026ffb95411e66042078d918a1" })
```

But if you need to use headers, you can code like that:

```
HTTParty.post("https://www.coins-e.com/api/v2/market/WDC_BTC/",
    :headers => { "HeaderExample" => "THISISMYAPIKEYNOREALLY"})
```